# WPF ResourceDictionary Source change AssemblyShortName dynamically

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, mergeddictionaries, assembly-name

I add a ResourceDictionary at Xaml.

Next, I add ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries as below:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Styles/TotalResources.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

I want to change AssemblyShortName "MyApp" when I change AssemblyName.

Can I just change "MyApp" On Xaml dynamically?